# Does a React.js app get entirely shipped to the browser on request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, browser

This is going to sound like a really dumb question but does the entire React app get shipped to the browser on first page load? Or is it shipped to the browser as-needed? If it is shipped as-needed then who decides what is needed when?

Let's say its a 3-pager. (e.g. /login, /users, /users/:userId).

I can probably just inspect the network calls or curl my server... but I consider that anecdotal and would like to get a more comprehensive idea.

Comment: it depends on how you have it built. It can definitely be separated into parts and have certain parts brought in on demand.

Comment: @KevinB where does that separation happen? Is done at the directory level? Is it done in the source code of the react app? is it done on the server?

Comment: Mine is done at the route level. For example, my root page loads in app.part.js, vendor.part.js, and 0.part.js, and then each additional route has it's own n.part.js that gets loaded in the first time each of those are requested. (handled by webpack)

Comment: ok so its a web pack thing. if one is not using web pack then probably one's app is not getting modularized

Comment: I'm sure there's other ways, webpack is just flavor of the month.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem specific to React, and is called choosing a bundling strategy, which translates to how you ship to the browser the resource files (js, css etc). In demand vs full preload vs a mix of the former ... It really depends on how you structured your app. For example, there are many apps which load the different parts of the application route based. This would be doing it in demand. There are pros / cons to the different approaches, and you should generally consider your bundle size, caching strategies etc.

I suggest you look at [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/), which is kind of today's standard for achieving this.

Comment: where does that separation happen? Is done at the directory level? Is it done in the source code of the react app? is it done in the source code of the server? 

Is it the case that by default, without any intentionality, that the entire react/angular app will be shipped as on huge "bundle" ?

Comment: normally the way it works is webpack (or similar bundling tool) inspects your application code dependencies and outputs a bundle file (or multiple) which then the browser can load. Is not part of the react app nor the server code. Is just another file in the directory (or cdn etc.)

Comment: so if one is not using webpack (or does not configure one's similar bundling tool) then simply put: no bundling happens

Comment: Exactly. I suggest you read a bit more on the subject before  deciding an approach.